# ReactJS adding Insights/Analytics for a Specific User

Tags: reactjs, react-native, analytics

I have a task where I want to collect and display insight for a specific users in my app and also display these data in another page in my App. I have a react App and react-native app to collect the data from

Some examples of these insights:

- Post View Count
- Profile Visit Insights
- CTA Buttons Click

What is the best approach here, Can I use third Party services like Google Analytics or something else, is it possible to fetch google Analytics data per user ?

Or should I just create new APIs for every insight and fetch these data to display them in my app ?

Thanks in Advance.